# Is there a complex analogue of the observed Fisher information?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, fisher-information

The observed Fisher information is the variance of the score.  The score is the gradient of the log-likelihood $\ell$ with respect to the parameter vector $\theta \in \mathbb R^n$.

What if the parameter vector were complex $\theta = x + yi$ for $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$?

Suppose the log-likelihood is smooth, and consider the "complex score": $v = \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial y}i$.  Then, the observed Fisher information would be the variance matrix $\mathbb{E}(v v^{\ast})$, which tells us how much the score varies as we wiggle $\theta$.

Now just like with complex Gaussians, we could have a pseudo-covariance matrix that gives us directional information: $\mathbb{E}(vv^{\intercal})$.  Is there a name for this term?